# Kafks consumer.poll returns no data

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have two Kafka (2.11-0.11.0.1) brokers. Default replication factor of topics is set to 2. Producers write data only to zero partition.

And I have scheduled executor which runs the task periodically. When it consumes a topic with a small number of records per minute (100 per minute) then in works like a charm. But for huge topics (10K per minute) method *poll* returns no data.

The task is:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

public final class TopicToDbPump implements Runnable {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TopicToDbPump.class);
  private final String topic;
  private final TopicPartition topicPartition;
  private final Properties properties;

  public TopicToDbPump(String topic, Properties properties) {
    this.topic = topic;
    topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, 0);
    this.properties = properties;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try (final Consumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties)) {
      consumer.assign(Collections.singleton(topicPartition));
      final long offset = readOffsetFromDb(topic);
      consumer.seek(topicPartition, offset);
      final ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
      if (records.isEmpty()) {
        log.debug("No data from topic " + topic + " available");
        return;
      }
      saveData(records.records(topic));
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      log.error("Etl process " + topic + " failed with exception", t);
    }
  }
}
```

Parameters of consumers are:

```
"bootstrap.servers" = "host-1:9092,host-2:9092",
"group.id" = "my-group",
"enable.auto.commit" = "false",
"key.deserializer" = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
"value.deserializer" = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
"max.partition.fetch.bytes": "50000000",
"max.poll.records": "10000"
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kafka Consumer API does not guarantee that the first call to `poll()` will return any data.

The Consumer first has to connect to the cluster, discover leaders for all partitions it's assigned to. As you imagine this can take a few seconds so it's unlikely data will have arrived immediately.

You should instead call `poll()` several times if no data is returned first.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! I've knowk about a timeout between an assignment of a partition and getting results in `poll` using `subscribe` method. But I somehow thought that manual assignment of a partition would cause getting data mmediately.